# Firebase Auth User object: how to access the "Created" or "SignedIn" attributes?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm trying to read, in code (python), the "created" and "signed in" dates that show on the Firebase Authentication console (Users tab). Anyone knows how to get to these attributes? I cannot find them in the docs. Thanks!

I tried print(str(user.signed_in)) and other syntactic variations, to no avail.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
    if user.email is None:
        print(str(user.uid))        # WORKS
        print(str(user.created))    # DOESN'T
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be in `user.user_metadata`.
Learn more about the properties of the [user record](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#userrecord) in the official references.

Comment: Thank you. Well documented, my fumble.